# cypress browser sends all cookies in all requests

Tags: cookies, browser, cypress

I am using cypress for e2e testing with the [session storage feature](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session) enabled.
Until recently the only two cookies in the project were "access_token" and "refresh_token". Now I added 2 more cookies which store some data which will automatically be written and read while you're using the website.

When browsing the website with any native browser (chrome, firefox, edge), no cookies get sent by the frontend to the backend in the request. Only the "access_token"s content will be used as the Authentication bearer.
When browsing in any browser inside cypress or letting cypress automatically browse, all cookies which exist will be added to every sent request. Not only requests sent by `cy.request()` but also the requests which the frontend natively sends.

This is a problem since the header size gets to large and the backend wont accept it. The quickfix was to increase the accepted header size in the backend but I'd prefer not sending the cookies at all.

Is there a way to tell cypress which cookies to send or prevent sending cookies at all? I don't really care which cookies will be stored in the cypress session. Only which cookies get sent.

**EDIT:**

All cookies use "strict" same site settings.
When testing against a deployed system https is used but with an invalid certificate.
When testing against a locally running system http is used.

The cookies only get sent when running cypress against a local system (localhost).

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS? Also, how have you configured the cookie samesite attribute?

Comment: All used cookies use "strict" same site settings.
When testing against a deployed system I use https but with an invalid certificate. When testing against a locally running system I use http. But I noticed the cookies only get sent when testing against a locally running system.

Answer (score 0):

Using samesite=strict means that the cookie will never be included in requests to other sites, so I guess that is your core problem here. You need to use samesite=none to get cookies included in HTTP POST Request across sites.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: But I don't want any cookie to be included in any request at all.  
When in production the browser extracts the value of the "access_token" and sends it as the security bearer, not as a cookie. No cookie is sent there. I don't want cypress to send any cookie either.